# Views alphabetical sorting problem for non-English language

Tags: 7, views

I want to sort one of the views I created alphabetically but there is a problem (I'm sorting taxonomy terms by grouping them with the first letters):

The website's language is Turkish and in Turkish alphabet there is a letter between C and D: **Ç**.

**While sorting, the list appears as this:**

#### A B Ç C D...

but it should be:

#### A B C Ç D...

**How to fix that? Is it about views or something else like MySQL etc?**

Comment: I think you're right with your final line, I believe views sorting is done at the database level.

Comment: Problem still exists, any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Not really an issue for this site since it is a problem at the database level.  Try searching online for "MySQL sort Turkish" or whichever db you're using.

Comment: Or, ask a similar question on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).