# How to correctly sort on accented letters when using the Lexicon module?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm facing an issue with the [Lexicon](https://www.drupal.org/project/lexicon) module which I still can't figure out.

I have a glossary of French terms, **sorted** alphabetically. And I notice that the **accented letters** are considered as different letters and make the words appear at the end of the list.

Example:

- Dettes
- Dividende
- Droit de souscription
- D**é**bit/crédit
- D**é**pôt de bilan

I found an issue reported [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1275954), that seems to match with my own problem.

I tried to apply the last validated [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/lexicon-transliteration_for_lexicon-1275954-13.patch), using my `.make` file like this:

```
projects[lexicon][patch][] = "https://www.drupal.org/files/lexicon-transliteration_for_lexicon-1275954-13.patch"
```

And proceeding to a deployment, using `phing` like this:

```
phing clean
phing dev-deploy
drush cc all
drush updatedb -y
drush fra -y
drush cc all
```

But it changed nothing.

**EDIT:**

- The patch is applied correctly.
- **In the DB**, when I sort the terms by "name", it appears in the **right order**.

Any clue is welcome!

Comment: Is it about MySql as I said there: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139315/views-alphabetical-sorting-problem-for-non-english-language

Comment: Thanks @herci but, as I said in my edit, the sorting looks right in my DB. Was it the case for you too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out whether or not the patch is applied correctly, open up `lexicon.admin.inc` and look for this code

```
if ($form_state['values']['lexicon_clear_filter_cache_on_submit'] == 1) {
 _lexicon_clear_filter_cache(NULL, TRUE);
function lexicon_alphabet_form($form, &$form_state) {
 '#type' => 'textarea',
 '#title' => t('Enter all the digits of your alphabet, in the correct order.'),
 '#default_value' => implode(' ', variable_get('lexicon_digits', range('0', '9'))),
 '#description' => t("Separate the digits by a blank. If you don't want terms to start with digits, leave this blank."),
);
```

If the patch has been applied successfully it will look like this

```
function lexicon_alphabet_form($form, &$form_state) {
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Enter all the digits of your alphabet, in the correct order.'),
  '#default_value' => implode(' ', variable_get('lexicon_digits', range('0', '9'))),
  '#description' => t('Separate the digits by a blank. If you don\'t want terms to start with digits, leave this blank.'),
  '#rows' => 1,
 );

$form['transliteration'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Enter transliteration rules used for indexing terms.'),
  '#default_value' => _lexicon_transliteration_ruleset_encode(variable_get('lexicon_transliteration', array())),
  '#description' => t('Use the syntax "é:e,è:e,ê:e,...". Transliteration rules are only applied internaly for indexing. Terms are displayed unchanged.'),
  '#rows' => 1,
);
```

Notice inside the function `lexicon_alphabet_form`, in the `'#description'` attribute `don't` changed to `don\'t` and also the `$form['transliteration']` was added in the patch. If you don't see these changes inside `lexicon.admin.inc` then the patch was not applied correctly. If you do, then the patch did not fix your problem. Hopefully this will help you narrow down where the problem is.

EDIT:

If the patch has been applied successfully,  go into the lexicon administration page and set the transliteration rules. Looking at the patch, it looks like it added a textfield for defining the rules you want to use in the following syntax `é:e,è:e,ê:e,...`

Comment: Thanks! The patch is apparently applied. I'm gonna update my question to clarify it.

Comment: Have you gone into the lexicon administration page and set the transliteration rules? Looking at the patch, it looks like it added a textfield for defining the rules you want to use in the following syntax `é:e,è:e,ê:e,...`

Comment: Can I answer you tomorrow morning while I'm back at work? I'm sorry I have no access to my project from outside my office. ;)

Comment: That was so obvious, I feel so stupid to forget to check the config after patching. Of course the textfield stands just there and I just have to set the rules myself. Thank you so much. Maybe you can edit your answer to make that part appears in it, so I can check it as the right answer? You made my Christmas merry x)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the suggestion of setting the transliteration rules.